# How do I use a different input on different currency pairs

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, tradingview-api

As part of a strategy I am using a price.input() function to enter a trade, so when price hits this level something happens. however when I change this value it changes it on different currency pairs as well.

For example if the key level on GBP/USD = 1.20000
and in the indicator, I set PRICE (my price.input variable) to 1.20000

later on I use the same indicator on another currency pair like the USD/CAD and set PRICE to 1.8000

when I go back to my GBP/USD chart, the price input has changed to 1.80000, which isnt what I want,
as I want it to remain 1.20000

Therefore is there a way where I can have different PRICE's for different Currency Pairs.

I have pasted the code below.

```
indicator("2 Candle Continuation", overlay = true)

openBarPrevious = open[1]
closeBarPrevious = close[1]
openBarCurrent = open
closeBarCurrent = close

PRICE = float(input.price(defval =0, title='SELECT PRICE', confirm=true))


UP_CONTINUATION = (closeBarPrevious > openBarPrevious ) and (closeBarCurrent > openBarCurrent) and (openBarCurrent >= closeBarPrevious) and (closeBarPrevious > PRICE)


DOWN_CONTINUATION = (closeBarPrevious < openBarPrevious ) and (closeBarCurrent < openBarCurrent) and (closeBarCurrent <= openBarPrevious) and (openBarPrevious < PRICE)


UP_BAR_COLOUR = if UP_CONTINUATION == true
    color.rgb(0, 255, 0)

DOWN_BAR_COLOUR = if DOWN_CONTINUATION == true
    color.purple

barcolor(color=UP_BAR_COLOUR,show_last = 10)
barcolor(color=DOWN_BAR_COLOUR,show_last = 10)

alertcondition(UP_CONTINUATION, title = "2 CANDLE UP", message = '[CurrencyPair], 2 CANDLE UP')
alertcondition(DOWN_CONTINUATION, title = "2 CANDLE DOWN", message = "[CurrencyPair], 2 CANDLE DOWN")
```

I expected the above code to work as I thought the input would change on different currency pairs but it did not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - Does this help you?

I've added a TICKERID section where you can add your own ticker name data and assign the relevant PRICE variables to each ticker.

You may want to use `syminfo.tickerid` rather than `syminfo.ticker` - it depends on your preference for retrieving exchange data.

```
//@version=5
indicator("2 Candle Continuation", overlay=true)

openBarPrevious     = open[1]
closeBarPrevious    = close[1]
openBarCurrent      = open
closeBarCurrent     = close

PRICE = input.float(defval=0, title='SELECT PRICE')

//TICKER ID's (Repeat lines to fill with your requirements)
PRICE := syminfo.ticker == "ETHBTC" ? 0.072 : PRICE
PRICE := syminfo.ticker == "ETHUSD" ? 1200 : PRICE
PRICE := syminfo.ticker == "BTCUSD" ? 16000 : PRICE
//
//
//
//

plot(PRICE)

UP_CONTINUATION     = (closeBarPrevious > openBarPrevious ) and (closeBarCurrent > openBarCurrent) and (openBarCurrent >= closeBarPrevious) and (closeBarPrevious > PRICE)
DOWN_CONTINUATION   = (closeBarPrevious < openBarPrevious ) and (closeBarCurrent < openBarCurrent) and (closeBarCurrent <= openBarPrevious) and (openBarPrevious < PRICE)

UP_BAR_COLOUR   = UP_CONTINUATION   == true ? color.rgb(0, 255, 0) : na
DOWN_BAR_COLOUR = DOWN_CONTINUATION == true ? color.purple : na

barcolor(color = UP_BAR_COLOUR,show_last    = 10)
barcolor(color = DOWN_BAR_COLOUR,show_last  = 10)

alertcondition(UP_CONTINUATION, title = "2 CANDLE UP", message = '[CurrencyPair], 2 CANDLE UP')
alertcondition(DOWN_CONTINUATION, title = "2 CANDLE DOWN", message = "[CurrencyPair], 2 CANDLE DOWN")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the easiest ways to resolve this is to have mutiple chart layouts for different currency pairs, each containing your script, with their own price settings.

Rather than changing the currency pair you'd change the chart layout to another previously saved layout.

This could work for you but may have some inherent limitations, let us know!

Comment: Hi Crypster this did work, however it is a rather painful process to change the chart layout every time I want to look at a different currency pair, given that I use 12 different currency pairs it shouldn't be too much of an issue. But I feel there is a better way of doing this, but I am just not too sure.